# Allowing admin to login as any user using sessions

Tags: php, session

I have a user login system in place.  I am starting to create the admin area and would like to allow a logged in admin to login as any user (in a new browser window).  I already have a username/password system setup for each and am using sessions to store some data. I guess I didn't think this through a whole lot in the beginning as now I am kind of stuck on how to go about this.

After successful login of either I am storing info in `$_SESSION['account']` and using this as my main check if they are logged in or not on pages... `if(!$_SESSION['account']){...send to login page...}`

Users have one session and the admin has another.  I did this so the admin and the admin logged in as a user would be separate.  If I am logged in as admin and logged in as a user the session values of each do not interfere.... I can log out of the admin and stay logged in as a user and vice versa.

Now, I can't seem to figure out how to allow the admin to login as a user.  I was going to do a dropdown list, select a username, and open a new browser window as the logged in user.  Since I am using different sessions this is posing a problem, but the sessions must be different so they don't interfere.

Someone must have run into this situation before... any ideas?

**admin :**

```
// start the session and timer
session_name('Site_Admin');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.test.com', false, true);
session_start();
```

**user :**

```
// start the session and timer
session_name('Site_Login');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.test.com', false, true);
session_start();
```

**EDIT:**

I thought this through some more and here is the logic I came up with.  I will no longer be using two sessions, but rather one `session_name('Site_Login');`

When users login they have account info (first name, last name, id, username, email, etc that is often used) stored in `$_SESSION['user']`.  The admin on the other hand has information stored in `$_SESSION['admin']`.  Users and admins have access to totally different areas of the site and the session variables are completely different.

With this setup I can then do checks on each page for correct access as I was before :

```
if(!$_SESSION['user'])
{
    Header("Location: /"); //user login page
    exit;
}

or for admin pages

if(!$_SESSION['admin'])
{
    Header("Location: /admin/"); //admin login page
    exit;
}
```

Also, since I am using the same session now... if I am logged in as an admin all I need to do is set `$_SESSION['user']` to whatever user I want to login as that user on user pages.  In the admin area I can do my dropdown, set the sessions variables for the user, and open a new page in the user area.  Logout of user and logout of admin are handled properly by `unset($_SESSION['user']);` and `unset($_SESSION['admin']);` rather than destroying the entire session as I was previously.

If anyone sees any flaws with this logic please add comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the same and I use the similar strategy as in UNIX systems: *real user* (the real user logged in), and *effective user* (the one you are switched to). You then use either of these two based on context. For example, you use  *real user* for permission checking and *effective user* to attach record ownership in database etc.

#### Initialization:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['real_user'] = ... # check login credentials etc.
$_SESSION['effective_user'] = $_SESSION['real_user'];
$_SESSION['permission'] = ... # based on database: 'NORMAL', 'ADMIN', ...
```

#### User switch

Then I have a drop-down list which sets the `set_eff_user` option in the URL. It is handled by approximatelly this code:

```
if ($_GET['set_eff_user']) {
    if (!can_switch_to_user($effective_user)) # permission checking; typically, 
                                              # you allow this to admin only
        die("error: ....");

    $_SESSION['effective_user'] = $effective_user;
}
```

Note: permission checking is done using `$_SESSION['permission']`.

Comment: So you are doing everything in the same session then... I thought about it more today and that seems like the only option I can think of right now.  User info would be in $_SESSION['user'] and admin in $_SESSION['admin']... I would need to change quite a bit though.

Comment: @user756659, no, there's no `$_SESSION['user']` and `$_SESSION['admin']` in my solution. Or what do you mean by those variables? And how is admin not a user? Admin is user as any other user, it just has more privileges.

Comment: I was referencing how I would go about it... storing user info in one array and admin in another.  I realize admin is a user... just with different privileges of course, however, in my current setup I was keeping the two separate by use of entirely different sessions (the reason why I have different session names in my OP).

Comment: Maybe this is the problem of your design. What would be the "admin info" you refer to? Try to look at it differently - as I sketched. There's one *real* user logged in, this user has some privileges (raw user, admin, something in between...), and this user can be switched to some *effective* user. I've updated my post to include the privileges part.

Comment: I'm following you just our designs are different.  There is completely different information being stored and accessed by admins compared to users which is why I am keeping the info separate through different sessions.  My thought was if $_SESSION['admin'] then login as user (skipping validation) and setting $_SESSION['user'] to its account values for use... now I am logged in as the user (no different than how they would). Now, I would be 'logged in' as both admin and whatever user I wanted.